How to fetch blocked contacts list in android without making it default dialer
I need to display a list of blocked contacts from the device. I want to retrieve this information without setting my app as the default dialer. I understand that accessing blocked contacts usually requires specific permissions and may be limited by Android's security model, but I need to ensure the solution is compliant with best practices and privacy guidelines.
ContactsContract.BlockedContacts: I attempted to use ContactsContract.BlockedContacts to fetch blocked contacts. However, I encountered issues with permissions and compatibility across different Android versions.
Permissions: I have requested the necessary permissions, including READ_CONTACTS, but it seems that blocked contact information isn't directly accessible through standard methods.
My Requirements:
Accessing Blocked Contacts: How can I programmatically access the list of blocked contacts on a device?
Permissions and Privacy: What permissions do I need to request, and are there any privacy or security considerations I should be aware of?
Compatibility: How can I ensure compatibility with different Android versions and manufacturers?
